# What did the Doctor mean when he said that he'd "walked in universes where the laws of physics were devised by the mind of a mad man"?

Tags: doctor-who

From *The Rings of Akhaten*.

> **Doctor:** I walked away from the last Great Time War. I marked the passing of the Time Lords. I saw the birth of the universe and I watched as time ran out, moment by moment, until nothing remained. No time. No space. Just me. **I walked in universes where the laws of physics were devised by the mind of a mad man.** I've watched universes freeze and creations burn. I've seen things you wouldn't believe. I have lost things you will never understand. And I know things. Secrets that must never be told. Knowledge that must never be spoken. Knowledge that will make parasite gods blaze. So come on, then. Take it! Take it all, baby! Have it! You have it all!
>   <sub>*(Series 7, Episode 7, The Rings of Akhaten).*</sub>

Was he referring to anything specific that we've seen in an episode, or was he describing something that happened off-screen?

Comment: Maybe Castrovalva, in which he was almost trapped in a collapsing Escher-like space created by the Master?

Comment: The Celestial Toyroom?

Comment: [Why did the chicken cross the road?](https://youtu.be/WS2E-94NdWI)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Wow, that's creepy. I'm not sure I'm ready for old Who yet.

Comment: It's really a silly episode, but the Doctor said universes (plural); and there are at least three example episodes on this page where the laws of physics were dictated by a mad man (in said universe). If we ignore the laws of physics part there would be dozens more. I've been watching for over 30 years, the show has ups and downs but it's never boring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be a reference to the episode '[The Three Doctors](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Three_Doctors_(TV_story))', where they were transported to a planet within an anti-matter universe, where [Omega](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Omega) had been trapped (and not destroyed, as usually believed, during the event that provided the Time Lords with their power source), and his will determined the physical makeup of the universe.

Stealing from the article I've linked to:

> Jo asks who brought them here, and a loud booming voice declares, "I did!" From the shadows steps the legendary Time Lord, Omega. He was the solar engineer who created the supernova that powers Time Lord civilization. He was thought to be killed in the explosion, but in actuality he had been transported to the antimatter universe, where his will and thought turned the formless matter into physicality. Trapped, due to the fact that his will is the only thing maintaining reality, he vowed revenge on the Time Lords, whom he believes abandoned him to his fate.

And, from the article on Omega:

> Omega had transported through the black hole into another universe made of anti-matter. Omega shaped the universe by force of will and access to the black hole's singularity. He could even create simple life. Radiation destroyed his body. The gauntlets, armour and helmet he had designed to protect him from the corrosive effect of the anti-matter now constituted his physical form. At first he shaped his new world into a paradise. As the centuries rolled by he grew weary and depressed, feeling abandoned by his fellow Time Lords. The landscape slowly transformed into a drab, grey desert as he became depressed by the loneliness he was feeling. The universe that had become his home was unstable, unable to exist without a powerful will to give it form; he was trapped and completely unable to escape.

Depression and madness had long since overtaken him, but, like many tragic characters, his desire for revenge kept him (and his pocket universe) going.

Comment: It is never explained.  I however took it literally as I'll explain.  Note that season was hinting at a big secret that only the doctor knew.  Like Moffat was prone to do it seems he changed his mind mid-season and it fizzled out into being that he had a War Doctor incarnation.

Comment: I took it as implying that the Doctor had rebooted the entire universe post Time War and his secret was on the order of the "Skasis Paradigm" that could rewrite reality (School Reunion episode).  So Time War Ends-The universe plays from beginning to end-Doctor is outside of the universe-He is a mad man that created a new universe without the time war's events

Comment: And the Doctor visited this anti-matter universe, right?

Comment: @TheDarkLord [Yes](https://youtu.be/oyLqsU-6m-c).